# my parse query does not complete until after the rest of the app does, how do i stop this from happening?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks, pfquery

Below is the parse query, i am trying to display the categories in a collection view, but the `numberOfItemsInSection` method runs before `getCategories` has the time to pull information from parse. `numberOfItemsInSection` uses `getCategories _anArrayOfCategories` to return the number of categories in the collection view.

```
-(void)getCategories{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];   //calls retrieve messages method below

    //get Categories where the class name is Categories
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categories"];
    //- (void)selectKeys:(NSArray *)keys
    [query selectKeys:@[@"CName"]];
    //[query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

        else {
            _anArrayOfCategories = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"Test 1: Retrieved %lu Categories", (unsigned long)[_anArrayOfCategories count]);

        }
    }];

}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Add a call to `[self.tableView reloadData]` after setting `_arrayOfCategories`. Make sure the call is made on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Either update your table after the query finishes, or make the query on a previous controller and push to this controller after it completes. Remember that these are UI operations and need to be done on the main thread.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    else {
        _anArrayOfCategories = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        NSLog(@"Test 1: Retrieved %lu Categories", (unsigned long)[_anArrayOfCategories count]);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // UI operations on the main thread
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    }
}];
```

---

Edit: Just to make sure, as it's unclear from your post, you don't want to call this method from `numberOfRowsInSection`. Put it in `viewDidLoad` or something similar, and then have `numberOfRowsInSection` use the `_anArrayOfCategories` object.

Comment: Hey thank you very much, i got it to work by writing      _anArrayOfCategories = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"Test 1: Retrieved %lu Categories", (unsigned long)[_anArrayOfCategories count]);
            
            NSLog(@"%@",_anArrayOfCategories);
            
            //Remember that these are UI operations and need to be done on the main thread.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                
                [self.collectionView reloadData];   this is all being done inside a collection view controller. Thank you very much